# Gibberish route output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have link i created for editing post but the output looks gibberish

> href="http://web.app/admin/blog/post/post_id%20=%3E%20%24post_id/edit

When it should be

> href="http://web.app/admin/blog/post/2/edit

***URL***

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.blog.post.edit', ['post_id => $post_id']) }}">Edit</a>
```

***Route***

```
Route::get('/blog/post/{post_id}/edit', [
    'uses'  => 'PostController@getUpdatePost',
    'as'    => 'admin.blog.post.edit'
]);
```

Comment: You have a missplaced quote: `['post_id' => $post_id]`

Comment: If you URL decode the link you get `http://web.app/admin/blog/post/post_id => $post_id/edit` which is basically saying that your route's post_id parameter is `post_id => $post_id` . This should indicate what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.blog.post.edit', ['post_id => $post_id']) }}">Edit</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.blog.post.edit', ['post_id' => $post_id]) }}">Edit</a>
```

You just had the quotes in the wrong place. This is very easy to spot if you have proper syntax highlighting, so I would highly recommend getting a blade syntax highlighter for your IDE or text editor if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked that was my typo mistake

Comment: But for the same example i used {{ route('admin.index') }} the result was like that

http://web.app/%7B%7B%20route('admin.index')%20%7D%7D

i am new to laravel i don't know what i am missing

Comment: Make a new question if you have another problem, it's out of the scope for this question.

Answer (score -4):

Replace

```
{{ route('admin.blog.post.edit', ['post_id => $post_id']) }}
```

with

```
{! route('admin.blog.post.edit', ['post_id => $post_id']) !}
```

---

{{}} means it will be echoed as it is

while

{!!} means it will be processed, and route() needs this

Comment: First, `{! !}` doesn't escape, `{!! !!}` does. Second, `route()` doesn't output any HTML, it outputs a URL, which does not need to be escaped.